# Yii2 GridView cannot set column width

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

this is the first time I am using the Yii2 GridView Widget. I have tried setting a column's width after reading some answers here on stackoverflow, but it just won't work for me and I would love it if the columns had different widths (especially the first one).

I have tried setting the width using 'contentOptions' directly for the first column and also with an external CSS file for the product name column.

Can someone please tell me if there is an alternative or if there is something I am doing wrong?

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width:20px;'],
        ],

        [
            'format' => 'raw', 
            'label' => 'Image',
            'value' => function ($data) { 
                $url = $data->imgSrc;
                return Html::img($url, ['width' => '40px']);
            },
        ],

        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'label' => 'Product name',
            'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return ['class' => 'tbl_name'];
            },
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 28):

If you want set width for single column you can use headerOptions:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
   'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:20%'],
],
```

Answer (score 12):

you have to set it like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute'=>'title',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:200px; white-space: normal;'],
            ],
        ]
    ]
);
?>
```

With contentOptions you can set options to all td for the column "title".
In Site.css is white-space set to nowrap by default.

```
.grid-view td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But if your content is longer than 200px for example, the col will be expand by content and ignores your with.

Answer (score 10):

First add Option like

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'options' => [ 'style' => 'table-layout:fixed;' ],
```

after that add below lines

```
[
    'attribute' => 'news_description',
    'contentOptions' => [ 'style' => 'width: 25%;' ],
],
```

Answer (score 6):

This could be the result of [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) css property, that will affect the table cell width depending on content in it. In my Yii2 project I had:

```
.grid-view td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

No one from advices provided here was not usefull for me. But this was usefull:

```
.grid-view td {
  white-space:pre-line; // or just 'normal'
}
```

Comment: Ohh man, you're champion! The only solution that has entirely solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you trying to achieve. But `max-width` with 20 pixels is probably not what you actually wanted. Try it with `width`:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px;'],  // not max-width
],
```

Comment: Okay. Then please tell us  what you're trying to achieve und what you currently get or see. Which width do you have? Do you have  an public URL?

Comment: I finally managed what I wanted to do, by using a workaround: while checking the CSS for the table, I noticed layout-table:fixed and I just added a new class for the table and set layout-table:inherit. What I saw  before was all the columns having the same width, so if I had say 2 columns, 50% width for each, for 3 columns - 33% and do on.

Answer (score 0):

Try with just `Options`:

```
 [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        'options' => ['style' => 'max-width:20px;'],
 ],
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but unfortunately, this won't work for me (I forgot to mention I did try it before, just tried it again and I got the same result) and I really don't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: It worked for me. Did you check in firebug. Does the property get applied?

Comment: I guess it does, I only viewed the page source, and it seemed like the corresponding td tags were added the style. I also noticed that when removing the header part of the grid, it does work, but that was not what I needed since you can use the hearder for sorting. In the end, while checking the CSS for the table, I noticed layout-table:fixed and I just added a new class for the table and set layout-table:inherit. I know it's a workaround, but it seems to be working the way I need it to work. Still don't know why any of the other solutions won't work. Thank you for the help, nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that has entirely solved the problem was the one suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2053862/rostyslav-pylypenko:
Here is the trick:

```
td {
  white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple but functional solution is to create a CSS setting a max-width for the columns. The `!important` flag is to ensure that this property doesn't get overrriden.

```
td {
  max-width: 800px;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Then, you just register it in your view.

```
$this->registerCssFile('css/tableColumnMaxWidht.css');
```

We have and example of this table working in this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2vbX.png).