# Yii2. How can I specify width only for the certain column in GridView widget?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I need to specify width for the certain column ('file_name' for example). I have tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976065/yii2-gridview-cannot-set-column-width) suggestions but it doesn't work for me.

One of the possible solutions is to make columns resizable but I don't know how to do it either.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'],
    'options'=>['style' => 'white-space:nowrap;'],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'lastname',
        'firstname',
        'middlename',
        'rs_account',
        'sum',
        'file_name',
        'state',
        'history_id',
        [
            'label' => 'Code',
            'attribute' => 'codes.code',
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: @Kevin would like to know if you solved the problem

Comment: @Kevin, no, unfortunately. And now I do not have access to the source code and can not test other possible solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You should use contentOptions for the every single attribute you want to style

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'tableOptions'=>['class'=>'table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'],
  'options'=>['style' => 'white-space:nowrap;'],
  'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      'lastname',
      'firstname',
      'middlename',
      'rs_account',
      'sum',

      ['attribute' => 'file_name',
         'label' =>'Filename'
         'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:680px;  min-width:600px;  '],
      ],
      'state',
      'history_id',
      [
          'label' => 'Code',
          'attribute' => 'codes.code',
      ],
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: I have tested this code many times.. have you an error .? . the result is not what you need . ?  please explain what do you mean with doesnt'work ..

Comment: The width of the column is equal to content in it. When I write your code, then specify the column width to 30px and refresh page just nothing changes.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I don't know why. If I change tableOptions it's working. But changes applied to the specific field just ignored. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: Just for test ... try without table-condensed in tableOptions

Comment: you could try to min-width or max-width

Answer (score 0):

use headerOptions:

```
      [
        'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
        'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width:20%'],
      ],
```